# SSTP VPN on Ubuntu 20.04 - can't install sstp network-manager plugin

Tags: network-manager, vpn

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 and have problem when I try install sstp network-manager plugin. In old versions I used the repository ppa:eivnaes/network-manager-sstp and it worked! but on 20.04 I have problems with some dependencies:

```
sstp-client : Depende: libevent-2.1-6 (>= 2.1.8-stable) mas não é instalável
               Recomenda: network-manager-sstp mas não será instalado ou
                          network-manager-sstp-gnome mas não será instalado
E: Impossível corrigir problemas, você manteve (hold) pacotes quebrados.
```

Is there a way to use sstp vpn with network-manager plugin on Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Yes: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NetworkManager/VPN Full instructions on how to compile it are there.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone trying it now, you can install it now "the standard way":

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:eivnaes/network-manager-sstp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install network-manager-sstp sstp-client
```

Comment: I try from the hard way from the top comment but that was so many dependencies, I try this one and done very well.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the functionality of these packages is already part of Ubuntu 20.04?

At my university, we were asked to install `network-manager-sstp` in order to connect to the university VPN.

Using **Settings > Network > VPN > Add > Point-to-Point Tunneling Protocol (PPTP)** worked just fine without installing anything and had all the settings described in the tutorial for setting up VPN with `network-manager-sstp` (tutorial was for Ubuntu 19.10 eoan).

Answer (score 0):

Eivind Næss has not (yet) updated his work for 20.04
So the package is not (yet) available for Focused Focal

You can try to compile it yourself from [git sources](https://github.com/enaess/network-manager-sstp) or try to manually install [deb 19.10 packages](https://launchpad.net/~eivnaes/+archive/ubuntu/network-manager-sstp?field.series_filter=eoan)

Comment: Focused Focal? Is that autocorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response!

Today I did the compiling from git sources and it's work — the plugin is showed on gnome network manager, but the sstp connection not working, please see the picture log below the message!

However, if someone need to compiler NetWork Manager SSTP  I will show you the steps:

```
sudo apt-get install ppp-dev libevent-dev libssl-dev build-essential libgtk-3-dev libsecret-1-dev libp11-kit-dev libgnutls28-dev
wget http://packages.linuxmint.com//pool/upstream/n/network-manager-applet/libnma-dev_1.8.10-2ubuntu3mint1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libnma-dev_1.8.10-2ubuntu3mint1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -y gnutls-bin
git clone https://github.com/enaess/network-manager-sstp.git
cd network-manager-sstp
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
```

Unfortunately the vpn with sstp yet not work, I have problem because can't I get connect. I don't know whre is the problem.

When I try to connect, the message is showed in `/var/log/syslog`:

[image]

I can't debug the problem with the command:

```
sudo NM_PPP_DEBUG=1 /usr/libexec/nm-sstp-service --debug
```

[image]

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I could make works here, in a new 20.04 install. 
First, I have add the ppa, but changed for eoan lines
It will be like that:

```
$cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/eivnaes-ubuntu-network-manager-sstp-focal.list 

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/eivnaes/network-manager-sstp/ubuntu eoan main

deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/eivnaes/network-manager-sstp/ubuntu eoan main
```

Than, we cannot install sstp-client yet by broken dependencies. so i get the source by apt as in that tutorial:
https://wiki.debian.org/BuildingTutorial#configure_apt
I recommend make some dir and cd in it, than:

```
apt-get source sstp-client #(i just needed to do for this package)
cd sstp-client-1.0.13 #source dir
sudo apt-get build-dep
sudo    debuild -b -uc -us
sudo dpkg -i ../*.deb #it will be 3 .deb packages in ../
```

now, you will be able to install network-manager-sstp from eivnaes eoan ppa

`sudo apt install network-manager-sstp network-manager-sstp-gnome`

If that not works, just `sudo service network-manager-restart`

Answer (score 0):

**Worked for me on Xubuntu 20.10**

### First of all, get libevent-2.1-6

It's required by SSTP-Client
Install it manually, instructions here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libevent-2.1-6/download

Or you can download and install it directly:

```
$ wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/libe/libevent/libevent-2.1-6_2.1.8-stable-4build1_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i libevent-2.1-6_2.1.8-stable-4build1_amd64.deb
```

### Add the Repository

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:eivnaes/network-manager-sstp`

And after adding it, change the distribution field of the added repository (in Software & Updates, command `software-properties-gtk`) to `eoan` or `bionic`. After that, update your repositories through the GUI or by running `sudo apt update`.

### Install SSTP-Client

Finally, install the SSTP-Client

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-sstp  sstp-client
```

Answer (score 0):

Packages has been updated for Hirsute (21.04) and Impish (21.10). Groovy (20.10) is already end of lifed as of July 22, 2021.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe that helps anyone:

I had to add the ppa repository manually. The ppa [https://launchpad.net/~eivnaes/+archive/ubuntu/network-manager-sstp](https://launchpad.net/%7Eeivnaes/+archive/ubuntu/network-manager-sstp) obviously only does not support hirsute hippo but only focal fossa at the moment of writing this answer.

Thus to add the repository I added a file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sstp-client.list with the content:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/eivnaes/network-manager-sstp/ubuntu focal main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/eivnaes/network-manager-sstp/ubuntu focal main
```

I suppose it is neccessary to do: `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 61FF9694161CE595` as stated here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/sstp-client/files/sstp-client/

But I did not get a connection to my workplace VPN either. I do hope it is not a problem with my method of installation (mixing ubuntu releases in the repositories).